Issue Adding Custom OrderItem to OrderGraph in B2B Commerce CartExtension.CheckoutCreateOrder
I'm working on a B2B Commerce extension, extending the CartExtension.CheckoutCreateOrder to add custom OrderItem details to an OrderGraph. However, when I attempt to add an OrderItem (in this case, a "Surcharge" item), the OrderSummary is not created, and no error is thrown. The OrderGraph shows success in the logs, but the OrderItem doesn’t appear as expected.
Here’s the code where I'm adding the OrderItem:
OrderItem surcharge = new OrderItem();
surcharge.OrderId = order.Id;
surcharge.Description = 'Surcharge';
surcharge.Quantity = 1.0;
surcharge.Type = 'Order Product';
surcharge.ListPrice = 100.0;
surcharge.UnitPrice = 100.0;
surcharge.LineNumber = 99;
surcharge.TotalLineAmount = 100.0;
surcharge.EstimatedDeliveryTimeZone = 'GMT';
surcharge.Product2Id = '01tMA000005iYKtYAM'; // Product is active and has a PricebookEntry
orderGraph.addNode(surcharge);

Expected Behavior:
After adding the surcharge OrderItem, I expect it to appear in the OrderSummary, as well as in the B2B Commerce interface.
Current Behavior:
When this code is executed, the OrderSummary is not created, and the added OrderItem does not appear in the final order, even though no errors are thrown. The B2B Commerce OrderGraph also shows success.
Additional Context:
The product used for the surcharge (Product2Id = '01tMA000005iYKtYAM') is active and has a PricebookEntry.
The platform is based on Salesforce B2B Commerce LWR with CartExtension.
Question:
Could there be additional requirements or constraints when adding an OrderItem to an OrderGraph in B2B Commerce? Are there specific steps to ensure OrderItems are correctly linked and displayed in the OrderSummary? Any insights or debugging steps would be greatly appreciated!
Here full code:
/**
 * Created by winardo on 7/24/2024.
 */

public virtual class CreateOrderService extends CartExtension.CheckoutCreateOrder {

    public virtual override CartExtension.CreateOrderResponse createOrder(CartExtension.CreateOrderRequest request) {
        CartExtension.Cart cart = request.getCart();
        CartExtension.CartItemList cartItemList = cart.getCartItems();



        CartExtension.CreateOrderResponse response = callDefault(request);
        CartExtension.OrderGraph orderGraph = response.getOrderGraph();
        List<OrderItem> orderItems = orderGraph.getOrderItems();

        Map<Id, Date> desiredDates = new Map<Id, Date>();
        Map<Id, Date> desiredDatesNotAvailable = new Map<Id, Date>();
        for(Integer i = 0; i < cartItemList.size(); i++){
            CartExtension.CartItem ci = cartItemList.get(i);
            desiredDates.put(ci.getProduct2Id(), (Date) ci.getCustomField('DesiredDate__c'));
            desiredDatesNotAvailable.put(ci.getProduct2Id(), (Date) ci.getCustomField('DesiredDateNotAvailable__c'));
        }

        for(OrderItem oi : orderItems){
            oi.DesiredDate__c = desiredDates.get(oi.Product2Id);
            oi.DesiredDateNotAvailable__c = desiredDatesNotAvailable.get(oi.Product2Id);
        }

        Order order = orderGraph.getOrder();

        System.debug('WILLY: ' + JSON.serialize(orderItems[0]));

        OrderItem surcahrge = new OrderItem();
        surcahrge.OrderId = order.Id;
        surcahrge.Description = 'Surcharge';
        surcahrge.Quantity = 1.0;
        surcahrge.Type = 'Order Product';
        surcahrge.ListPrice = 100.0;
        surcahrge.UnitPrice = 100.0;
        surcahrge.LineNumber = 99;
        surcahrge.TotalLineAmount = 100.0;
        surcahrge.EstimatedDeliveryTimeZone = 'GMT';
        surcahrge.Product2Id = '01tMA000005iYKtYAM';
        orderGraph.addNode(surcahrge);

        System.debug('willy: ' + order.Id);
        System.debug('willy: ' + order.Status);
        order.ChargeTo__c = (String) cart.getCustomField('ChargeTo__c');
        order.Carrier__c = (String) cart.getCustomField('Carrier__c');

        final Id accountId = order.AccountId;

        List<OrderDeliveryGroup> odgs = orderGraph.getOrderDeliveryGroups();
        if(!odgs.isEmpty()){
            OrderDeliveryGroup odg = odgs[0];
            ContactPointAddress cpa = B2BDao.getCPAFromOrderDeliveryGroup(odg, accountId);
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'CreateOrderService::createOrder::cpa::' + cpa);
            odg.Description = cpa.Id;
        }

        return response;
    }

    @TestVisible
    private virtual CartExtension.CreateOrderResponse callDefault(CartExtension.CreateOrderRequest request) {
        return super.createOrder(request);
    }


}

